# Add a Logout Launcher Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, icons, launcher, logout

When I search for "logout" in Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop, I get this icon:

[image: Logout icon]

I'd like to add it to the launcher for all users. I can't figure out where this icon comes from, it isn't a `.desktop` file under `/usr/share/applications`...

So, I guess I need to create a `.desktop` file to execute the `gnome-session-quit --no-prompt` command, but I'd rather use a cleaner method. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi.. When you click the icon are you sure it is not asking for confirmation?

Comment: `shutdown` `reboot` `switch user` `suspend` `logout` these are compiled in gnome shell to show when you type certain keywords in overview/show all apps screen. So the best way is to create shortcuts in `/usr/share/applications` as you mentioned.

Comment: I see I wasn't clear. My focus isn't the icon, but the functionality. I'd like to add a launcher for all existing and future users so the can log out. This is a University's Computer Lab machine and each student uses her/his own account. I want to make it easy for them to find the Log Out option.

Comment: Oh.. then a 4 line .desktop file is enough as per your initial idea..

Comment: That was the whole point for my question: What those four-line `.desktop` file be ?!

Answer (score 0):

For kubuntu 22.04, a file /usr/share/applications/logout.desktop with

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=logout
Icon=application-exit-symbolic
Exec=qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer org.kde.KSMServerInterface.logout 0 0 0
```

and a soft link on the desktop worked

```
ln -s /usr/share/applications/logout.desktop ~/desktop/logout.desktop
```

Answer (score -1):

Keeping below text in the file `/usr/share/applications/logout.desktop` will do the job.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=logout
Icon=application-exit-symbolic
Exec=gnome-session-quit
```

Comment: First, I had to install 
sudo apt install gnome-session-bin
Second, it did not work:
When I run gnome-session-quit on the console, I get:

** (gnome-session-quit:29887): WARNING **: 23:13:06.960: Failed to call logout: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

Comment: The question refers to Ubuntu 20.04. You are comparing it with Kubunu, thats why `gnome-session-quit` did not work for you. Thanks @Markus